# How do you align the tabs with the tab page in c#?

Tags: c#, alignment, border, tabcontrol

Ok, so I need to align the tabs with the tab pages in c#. I tried changing the size properties of the tabs and the pages but it doesn't help. It won't let me change the size property of the tab page to match the tab property size. I have also tried changing the font of the text on the tabs themselves. There may be some padding/border/etc. that keeps it from being aligned, I'm not sure. I also went into the tab control property "collection" and manually edited the margins/padding but couldn't get it to work. How do I get it to align? See image below.

[tabcontrol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmaJa.png)

Here is my code for the tab control:

```
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        tabControl.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(tabControl_DrawItem);
    }

    private void tabControl_DrawItem(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        Brush txtBrush;

        TabPage tabPage = tabControl.TabPages[e.Index];

        Rectangle tabBounds = tabControl.GetTabRect(e.Index);

        if (e.State == DrawItemState.Selected)
        {
            txtBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
            g.FillRectangle(Brushes.DarkGray, e.Bounds);
        }
        else
        {
            txtBrush = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(e.ForeColor);
            e.DrawBackground();
        } 

        Font tabFont = new Font("Proggy", 15, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

        StringFormat strFlags = new StringFormat();
        strFlags.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        strFlags.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        g.DrawString(tabPage.Text, tabFont, txtBrush, tabBounds, new StringFormat(strFlags));
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to ... *align the tabs within the tab control to the tab page* ?

Comment: Yes, or at least hide the borders.

Comment: You do understand that the alignment can only work if the Tab control height can be divided by the Tab pages count?